# Using multiple @theatreJs PerspectiveCamera for local and global camera animation

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, post-processing, react-three-drei

I am trying to create a visual illusion allowing a smooth transition from one scene to another using the `MeshPortalMaterial` from `react/three-drei`. To achieve this, I have tried using the `PerspectiveCamera` from `theatre.js` for the movement of the camera, but I have only little knowledge about the local position and the global position. So I decided to use two `PerspectiveCamera`, one placed inside the `MeshPortalMaterial`, with the other one placed outside of it. After spending some time tweaking the camera params using `threatre.js`, I managed to get it work as intended, a little bit janky, but it worked. I have attached a gif below the code.

1. I wonder if I can use only one camera throughout the whole experience?
2. Are there any better approaches to do this?
3. Any caveats I should know when using the `MeshPortalMaterial`?
4. In addition, I have been using components from `react-three/drei` like `Sky` and `Sparkles`, and I noticed turning on `EffectComposer` would mess up the color and the transparency of the material, I have tried using the `linear` colorspace management, but the color was still off. It's very noticeable in the gif below.

Please let me know if you need more info, I highly appreciate any help I can get, I have been struggling quite a bit. Thank you.

```
import { useRef } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { MeshPortalMaterial, ScrollControls, useScroll } from '@react-three/drei'
import { getProject, val } from '@theatre/core'
import studio from '@theatre/studio'
import extension from '@theatre/r3f/dist/extension'
import { editable as e, SheetProvider, PerspectiveCamera } from '@theatre/r3f'

import HomeScene from '@/src/components/scene/HomeScene'

const sheet = getProject('Portfolio Project').sheet('Portfolio Sheet')
studio.initialize()
studio.extend(extension)

const cameraConfig = {
    fov: 60,
    near: 0.1,
    far: 40
}

function Scene() {
    const windowPortalRef = useRef(null)
    const scroll = useScroll()

    useFrame(() => {
        const sequenceLength = val(sheet.sequence.pointer.length)
        sheet.sequence.position = scroll.offset * sequenceLength
    })

    return (
        <>
            <PerspectiveCamera
                theatreKey='Camera'
                makeDefault
                fov={cameraConfig.fov}
                near={cameraConfig.near}
                far={cameraConfig.far}
            />
            <mesh>
                <planeGeometry args={[5, 5, 1]} />
                <MeshPortalMaterial ref={windowPortalRef} blend={0}>
                    <PerspectiveCamera
                        theatreKey='Camera2'
                        makeDefault
                        fov={cameraConfig.fov}
                        near={cameraConfig.near}
                        far={cameraConfig.far}
                    />
                    <HomeScene windowPortalRef={windowPortalRef} />
                </MeshPortalMaterial>
            </mesh>
        </>
    )
}

export default function Experience() {
    return (
        <main className='fixed left-0 top-0 z-0 h-full w-full overflow-hidden'>
            <Canvas
                flat
                // linear
                // eventPrefix='client'
                // eventSource={document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement}

                gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
            >
                <ScrollControls pages={1} damping={0.5} maxSpeed={1}>
                    <SheetProvider sheet={sheet}>
                        <Scene />
                    </SheetProvider>
                </ScrollControls>
            </Canvas>
        </main>
    )
}
```

[image]